# Dynamically shrinking header - both text and images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to find an example of code that dynamically resizes both the header's height and also the logo image inside it like you can see if you visit here

http://www.kriesi.at/legal-information

I've seen examples like this

http://callmenick.com/post/animated-resizing-header-on-scroll

which alters the height and font size and I've had success playing with the samples, but they don't include images in the header and that's the bit I'm struggling with.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to do to the image in the header? scale it? remove it? change it?

Comment: If you want to scale the image then use css `transform` rule. My website have an example: http://angelangeles.esy.es

Comment: I'm trying to "dynamically resizes both the header's height and also the logo image inside it like you can see if you visit here http://www.kriesi.at/legal-information"

Love the site AAIII that's the kind of thing I'm aiming for.   The transform sorted out the graphic question, thanks...now I've just got to figure out how to do the rest ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shrink the logo, you can have different max-heights set on the image. This would be similar to changing the font size, but instead just change the max-height.

Your code could look something like:

```
header nav img {
    max-height: 88px;
}
header.smaller nav img {
    max-height: 44px;
}
```

Keep in mind that this will change the size of all images in the nav, so you may need a more specific selector if you have images in the nav other than the logo.